# ATK Framework : how to add costum html in nodes?

Tags: php, html

I started working on some old pages that use ATK Framework.

inside the classes (that extend atkNode) I would like to insert some attribute that should give me the possibility of write my custom html (more precisely a form that needs to be filled).

How can I achieve that?

```
$rel=&$this->add(new atkAttribute..... ???
```

Is this one the correct way?

I have no clue! Every idea is well accepted!

Comment: removed [atk4] tag, which is for different framework (Agile Toolkit)